# IE11 back button reloads page from cache but JS stops

Tags: internet-explorer

I am building a site which has a heavy reliance on JS (custom check/radio buttons, tabs, accordions, jquery etc) and I am using PHP minify to reduce the size of the scripts but I don't think this is the cause of the issue.

When I use the back button in IE the page reloads from its previous state (accordion is open etc) however some of the other functions (checkboxes, input validation) do not work.

If I hit refresh the page goes back to normal and everything works fine. I have tried adding PHP cache headers

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

and meta headers

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
```

but IE still loads the page from cache. Every other browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc) work fine. Is there a way to reload the page if the back button is clicked without using the refresh meta?

Comment: Perhaps this is caused by the [back-forward cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching)? You can easily wire up one of the cache events (e.g. `pageshow`) and determine from where the page is being retrieved. I've seen discrepancies in the implementations of the bfcache across browsers.

Comment: OK thanks. I will read over the link